# Meaning and use of ideograms around "language" : 说，话，语

Tags: translation, meaning, characters, difference, learning

I just arrived in this warm community and am glad to find a stackexchange about Chinese language. I merely began to learning Chinese and find it really exciting, yet many of uses and conventions are neither so clear to me, nor really explained -- or even underlined -- in my learning books and websites.

So here is my question: **I feel a bit confused concerning the different sinograms relatives to the language and the speech**. Here is what I induce from tremendously few examples and a lot of mystical extrapolations:

- **说 (shuo1)** means "to talk, to speak, to say" (i.e. talking in a general, theoretical way, referring to the idea/potentiality of speaking)
- **话 (hua4)** means "dialect, spoken word" (i.e. talking in a practical, pragmatic way, referring to the act/practical skill of speaking)
- **语 (yu3)** means "language" (i.e. the abstract building which is a language, endowed with its rules and theories)

Here I compared the three with two probable bias:

- I assume sinograms to have a proper meaning by itself, which seems to rarely be the case
- I propose the translations treating them sometimes as nouns, sometimes as verbs, even if it seems to be an irrelevant distinction in Chinese

Thus I add two more general questions about the Chinese language:

- Are sinograms really used sometimes by themselves and understood like that, or do they only carry a meaning when cristalized in a "word" ? (That is to say : is my question relevant or is it more a meta-question for linguists and language anthropologists ?)
- Do those three have "preferred" grammatical functions ? That 说 more often used as a verb and 语 more as a noun ? Or is my comparison of significations meaningful ?

谢谢 and sorry for the possible lack of precision :)

Comment: Something you may find interesting: Mandarin - 为什么说。。。 Cantonese - 点解话。。。

Comment: @rhughes Indeed, we are far from a language with a rigid meaning for its characters ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Chinese character has its meaning or meanings. Some can be used as a word on its own,

For example:

Noun:

- 人(person(/ people/ human)
- 火(fire)
- 山(hill/ mountain)

Verb:

- 殺(kill)
- 跑(run)
- 吃(eat)

Adjective:

- 大(big)
- 小(small)
- 好(good)

However, the majority of Chinese words are composed of two characters.

For example:

- 正確(correct)
- 討論(discuss/ discussion)
- 明白(understand)

*See reference [here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/21875/how-to-determine-if-character-can-be-used-separetely)

As for your question:

- **說** is mostly a verb for "**speak**" or "**talk**" but it can combine with other characters to form more specific words. For example: 演說 (lecture/ public speech), 說服(convince/ persuade), 說明(explain)
- **話** is mostly a noun for "**spoken words**" but it can combine with other characters to form more specific words, for example: 謊話(lie), 說話(speak/ talk) , 對話(conversation)
- **語** is mostly a noun for "**language**" but it can combine with other characters to form more specific words, for example: 語言(language), 英語 (English), 語音(speech tone)

Many characters' original meaning had became obsolete. These characters only become meaningful when they are a part of a "two characters word" or a part of a "four characters phrase". One good example would be "黷" in "[窮兵黷武](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/60796/)" . The character: "黷" itself originally meant "act wantonly" but today, no one would use this character on its own except in the idiom 窮兵黷武.

Comment: Thank you very much Tang Ho for your answer. I am beginning to learn, and many books and applications learn us the meaning of single characters, "real" words coming later. Hence I stick a little on those meaning... and it remains an efficient tool to remember more efficiently the words ;)

Answer (score 0):

as  a Chinese we can say 说，means talk ,it'sjust a ver, 
话 means a sentence, these two words  are often used  on dailylife